# Can onCheckedChanged method be called with no interaction?

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged

I have a custom `ListView` where clicking an item fires a new `Activity`.
Each row of the `ListView` has a `CheckBox` and a `TextView`.

This is the `getView` method from my custom `ListView`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.puzzles_row, null);
        }
        ListedPuzzle lp = items.get(position);
        if (lp != null) {
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitles);
            title.setText(lp.getTitle());
            CheckBox star = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.star_listed);
            star.setChecked(lp.isStarred());
            star.setTag(new Integer(position));

            star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    Integer realPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    ListedPuzzle obj = items.get(realPosition);
                    starListedPuzzle(obj.getId(), isChecked);
                }
            });

        }
        return v;

    }
```

The `onCheckedChanged` is called when coming back from the another Activty, without possible user interaction to actually check anything.

The point is that used to work fine and haven't really change anything. I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913687/checkbox-changes-value-twice) that it's a bug but can't really believe it.

It always calls the method on the same two items of the `ListView`. Could they be set to `checkedChange=true` somehow?

Answer (score 11):

It can be called on onRestoreInstanceState within your fragment

You may disable that with

```
android:saveEnabled="false"
```

on the Checkbox's layout definition

Comment: This is the best solution for a really annoying problem. If onCheckedChanged() is being called unexpectedly try this.

Answer (score 10):

I have a feeling it is happening in the `onRestoreInstanceState` method. Android automatically handles restoring the state of most `View`s in your activity when it is paused and resumed. When being resumed, it sounds like it's restoring the checked state of your `CheckBox` objects, which is triggering `onCheckedChanged`. Try doing this in your `Activity` and let me know if this solves your problem:

```
private boolean mRestoringInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    mRestoringInstanceState = true;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState( savedInstanceState );
    mRestoringInstanceState = false;
}
```

Then change your `onCheckChanged` method like so:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked) {

    if(!mRestoringInstanceState) {
        Integer realPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
        ListedPuzzle obj = items.get(realPosition);
        starListedPuzzle(obj.getId(), isChecked);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Probably a better/easier solution would be to assign the listener in the `onResume` method instead since it gets called after `onRestoreInstanceState`. Note that you wouldn't implement any of the above if using this solution:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    CheckBox star = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.star_listed);
    star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // onCheckedChanged implementation
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit2:** Just realized you're doing this in an `Adapter`. This may not be related to `onRestoreInstanceState`, but I think I see the problem. You are reusing `View`s in the `Adapter`, which is good, but you're setting `star` to checked before setting the listener. The problem is that `star` already has a listener from the last time it came through the `getView` method. Before you call `star.setChecked()`, call `star.setOnCheckedChangedListener(null)` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Now, though, clicking on my CheckBox doesn't do anything ofcourse.

Comment: It should if you're setting `mRestoringInstanceState` back to `false` after `super.onRestoreInstanceState` finishes executing.

Comment: Additionally, you could also move the `star.setOnCheckedChangeListener...` line to the `onResume` method, as this gets called after `onRestoreInstanceState`. You wouldn't need to implement `onRestoreInstanceState` in this case. I'll edit my answer to show this option.

Comment: Well, it works like I said if I set `if(mRestoringInstanceState)`, but it doesnt work if I set `if(!mRestoringInstanceState)`

Comment: @JasonRobinson: Wouldn't your `onResume` solution also require the listener to be set to `null` in `onPause`?

Comment: @MisterSquonk No, I don't believe listeners are restored via `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: @eskalera I just realized you're doing this in an `Adapter` and not an `Activity`. Makes my solution not worthwhile for you. Let me give you another solution.

Comment: @eskalera Sorry I'm throwing you around to different answers, but check my 2nd edit.

Comment: @Jason Robinson thanks, don't worry. I was just realising your 2nd solution can't be achieved since the `CheckBox` hasn't been initialised yet.

Comment: @JasonRobinson, Working like a charm now! I'll keep dwelling on it for a while because didn't really get it yet. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @eskalera The reason it works like that is that since you are reusing views in `getView`, `star` already has a listener attached to it from the last time that view was passed through `getView`. So when you checked `star`, it trigger the last listener that was assigned to it. It's up to you to uninitialize this before checking it.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue as well using a custom Adapter.

I found checking if the button isShown solves the problem:

```
OnCheckedChangeListener ccl = new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

        if(buttonView.isShown())
        {

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I think this is a fine solution as the system invoking the OnCheckedChangedListener when it is itself restoring state is obviously not what 99% of developers want. It is worth mentioning that ViewCompat.isLaidOut(buttonView) also works for this purpose and isn't tied strictly to visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Check your stacktrace in the listener

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, isChecked) {
    <breakpoint here>
}
```

If you see `onRestoreInstanceState()` in the stacktrace you can use this in the layout:

```
<CheckBox
...
android:saveEnabled="false" />
```

... as suggested here:
[Android CheckBox -- Restoring State After Screen Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512010/android-checkbox-restoring-state-after-screen-rotation)

**or**

If you see that `star.setChecked()` is the one called from you `getView()` in the stacktrace then just remove the listener by `star.setOnCheckedChangedListener(null)` before `star.setChecked()` (then you can reset the listener as you do). Like Jason Robinson suggests.

Comment: saved my day :) though I was not using it in adapter.