# Android setOnCheckedChangeListener calls again when old view comes back

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, listener, expandablelistview

I cannot solve an issue with the getGroupView-method.

the problem is that the listener setOnCheckedChangeListener is getting invoked to many times.

Let say i check a certain checkbox-item. Then I scroll it out of view and then scroll back. What happends is that the listener is called once again. And the problem is that I store checkbox-id's in an arraylist inside this listener to use it later in the code. The consequence is that more elements is added to the arraylist everytime the listener is called and distortes the data.

Is there a solution to this? what should I do? Should I for instance unregister the listener?

```
@Override
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view = null;

     final int group_position = groupPosition;
     if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_phrase, parent, false);
         final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.groupTitle);
         viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
         viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                    checked.add((Integer) viewHolder.checkBox.getTag());
                }
                else {
                    checked.remove((Integer) viewHolder.checkBox.getTag());
                }

            }
        });

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(groupPosition);

     } else {
         view = convertView;
         ((ViewHolder)view.getTag()).checkBox.setTag(groupPosition);
     }

     ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
     holder.text.setText(titles[groupPosition]);

     for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
         if (checked.get(i) == group_position) {
             holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
         }
         else if (checked.get(i) != group_position) {
             holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
         }
     }

     return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What version of Android are you using?

It seems to be an issue for multiple components, especially with a checkedChange() method (CheckBox, RadioButton) and I can't provide a good explanation why it is happening.

I would assume because it registers the change of the position state and grabs the change of other properties? A similar issue was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913687/checkbox-changes-value-twice)

In any case, a workaround around this could be to add an `OnClickListener()`.

```
CheckBox yourCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.yourId);

yourCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkIos checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                         //Case 1
        }
        else 
          //case 2

      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - an improvement!!! - the listener is not called again. And as a consequence of this is that the arraylist is not growing any more. Very good!!! But the problem is now that if I check let say 5 checkbox-items, scroll those out of view and the back - only one item is checked. Any Idea of how to solve this? (using min API 11)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309250/checkbox-gets-unchecked-on-scroll-in-a-custom-listview Could this help?

Comment: Accept the answer, maybe? :D

Comment: "t seems to be an issue for multiple components, especially with a checkedChange() method (CheckBox, RadioButton)" Thanks to this comments . Even I faced same kind of issue and replaced with onclicklistener .

Answer (score 23):

`OnCheckedChangeListener` worked for me with one if condition

```
if(buttonView.isShown())
{
    //ToDo code
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, the question was  in relation to setOnCheckedChangeListener, this answer addressed the subject of the actual question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! isShown() is indeed handy function on views.

Comment: This is the correct & right answer...Thanks @Sonal Bausakar

Answer (score 14):

Add the below to **ToggleButton** layout:

```
android:saveEnabled="false"
```

This would make sure android doesn't store the check state to `RestoreInstance` and in turn won't cause the state change experienced by you.

Answer (score 8):

Set the listener to **null** before calling **setCheck()** function, and **enable** it after that such as the following:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener (null);
checkBox.setChecked(true);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener (this);
```

Reference: [Change Checkbox value without triggering onCheckChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523157/change-checkbox-value-without-triggering-oncheckchanged)

Answer (score 5):

Add an additional if statement `isShown()` in the OnCheckedChange method and it solves the problem that the OnCheckedChangeListener gets called multiple times.
There is no need to change to an onClickListener:

```
@Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 
   if (buttonView.isShown()) { 
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 
             //Do something 
        } else { 
             //Do something 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**strong text**There is many way to solved the issue

```
checkBoxSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           // write here your code for example ...
              if(isChecked){
               // do somtheing when is checked
                   }else{
                       // do somthing when is removed the check**strong text**
                        }


        }
    });
```

**and there is  another way  **

```
    checkBoxSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
//do something
            }else{
//do something
}
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and struggled for several hours seeing all discussions related to this. I tried to fix this by keeping
`viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(groupPosition);`
this statement before `viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` this listener. And the code works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue and found a way around by using on click listener

First check if the checkbox has the onclicklistener assigned to it or not. If not that means the adapter is setting the value for the first.

```
if(!holder.checkbox.hasOnClickListeners())
        {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(data.get( position ).getSelected());

        }
```

Now after checking this

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    data.get( position ).setSelected(holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(data.get( position ).getSelected());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            data.get( position ).get_number()+" : "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Hopefully the scrolling issue goes away. Works fine here.