# Issues in Expandable listview

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

My requirement is in `ExpandbleListView` view add `CheckBox` to parent item and that parent item `CheckBox` controls child check box how to get this? how to add check boxes any one give solution?

> ExpandableList.java - Adapter class

```
public class ExpandableList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

Context Context;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> ChildItems;
private List<String> GroupItems;
HashMap<Integer,boolean[]> checkboxData;
CheckBox checkBox'
public ExpandableList(Context mContext, List<String> mGroupItems, HashMap<String, List<String>> mChildItems
                      ) {
    Context = mContext;
    ChildItems = mChildItems;
    GroupItems = mGroupItems;

}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return GroupItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ChildItems.get(GroupItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return GroupItems.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return ChildItems.get(GroupItems.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.group_list,null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupTitle);
    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tv.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   String listTitle = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_list,null);
    }
    TextView tvv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_list);
    tvv.setText(listTitle);
    tvv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
  CheckBox cb  = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCheckbox);

    return  convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private HashMap<String, List<String>>  ChildItemss;
private List<String> GroupItemss;
ExpandableList expandableList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listData();
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandblelist);
    expandableList = new ExpandableList(this,GroupItemss,ChildItemss);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableList);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, GroupItemss.get(groupPosition)+"Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, long id) {
       ChildViewHolder ch  = new ChildViewHolder();
            ch.childCheckbox  = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.listCheckbox);
           ch.childCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ChildItemss.get(childPosition)+"Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });

            return true;
        }
    });
}
public void listData()
{
    GroupItemss = new ArrayList<String>();
    ChildItemss = new HashMap<String, List<String>> ();

    GroupItemss.add("Cricket");
    GroupItemss.add("India");

    List<String> cricket = new ArrayList<>();
  cricket.add("sachin");
    cricket.add("dhoni");
    cricket.add("yuvi");

   List<String> india = new ArrayList<String>();
    india.add("modi");
    india.add("pawankalyan");

    ChildItemss.put(GroupItemss.get(0),cricket);
    ChildItemss.put(GroupItemss.get(1),india);
}
```

> items_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/items_listlayout">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:id="@+id/items_list"/>
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/listCheckbox"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> group_list.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/group_layout">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:id="@+id/groupTitle"/>
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/groupCheckbox"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml files as well . Since to the group view you haven't added and checkbox . The view seems to have just TextView

Comment: The issue is you are giving event to click listner for the groupview . Rather you should handle checked listner for the for the checkbox inside it.

Comment: can u tell how to do that.where i can write i cant understand please post that code

Answer (score 0):

Try this I tried for you . Modify as per your requirement.

```
package com.deeb.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.deeb.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by terril1 on 25/07/16.
 */
public class ExpandableList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements GroupItemClicked {

    Context mContext;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> ChildItems;
    private List<String> GroupItems;
    HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> checkboxData;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    GroupItemClicked itemClicked;
    boolean itemcheckedTrue;
    int pos;

    public ExpandableList(Context mContext, List<String> mGroupItems, HashMap<String, List<String>> mChildItems
    ) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        ChildItems = mChildItems;
        GroupItems = mGroupItems;
        itemClicked = this;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return GroupItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ChildItems.get(GroupItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return GroupItems.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ChildItems.get(GroupItems.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);
            holder.lblTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupTitle);
            holder.checkedItem = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupCheckbox);
            holder.lblTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.checkedItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //is chkIos checked?
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "clicked");
                        itemClicked.itemclicked(groupPosition, true);
                        //Case 1
                    } else {

                    }
                    //case 2

                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.checkedItem.setTag(groupPosition);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            (holder).checkedItem.getTag();
        }
        holder.lblTitle.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
        }
        TextView tvv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.items_list);
        tvv.setText(listTitle);
        tvv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCheckbox);
        if (itemcheckedTrue) {
            cb.setEnabled(true);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemclicked(int position, boolean status) {
        itemcheckedTrue = status;
        pos = position;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView lblTitle;
        CheckBox checkedItem;

    }

}


interface GroupItemClicked {
    void itemclicked(int position, boolean status);
}
```

Comment: For reference check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/q/17372750/1562755

Comment: what is case1 and case2

Comment: sir my requirement is when i am click on parent item group check box it will open list of child items and checked items also selected

Comment: Case 1 and case 2 are conditions when they are checked and unchecked

Comment: ok sir but my requirement is different then what is the procedure

Comment: @A.asha : So what u need is when the GroupView is clicked the childview data should be viewable ..  correct me if I am wrong

Comment: when groupview ccheckbox is checkked then child items is checkedwith respect to parent checkbox

Comment: that is my requirement

Comment: @A.asha : I have modified the code to showcase you the logic . Rest you can modify the logic more based on your requirement. If you think it's around your required answer please accept the answer.

Comment: Just don't copy paste the code . Add your logic as to what you want to when the check box is clicked. Check in this method if you get anything when the groupview is clicked @Override
    public void itemclicked(int position, boolean status) {
        itemcheckedTrue = status;
        pos = position;
    }

Comment: when the parent checkbox is clicked at that same time child checkboxes also checked

Comment: So what is the problem .. Did u debug the callback .. and based on the received callback did you refresh the expandablelistview