# onCheckedChanged is called whenever viewHolder is recycled

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-checkbox

I am writing a todo list application and, in particular, I want the value of the checkBox to be stored in the database every time it is changed.

I set this feature by adding `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TodosAdapter.TodoViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Todo todo = todoList.get(position);

        holder.todoTV.setText(todo.getText());
        holder.todoTV.setChecked(todo.isDone()); //isDone is a boolean that indicates whether the checkBox has been selected or not

        holder.todoTV.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                dbManager.allDao().setTodoIsDone(todo.getTodoId(), isChecked); //sets the isDone attribute of the database
                todo.setDone(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that onCheckedChanged is also called when the viewHolder is recycled and in these cases it returns isChecked = false;

[image]

Comment: when the view is recycled, is `buttonView` null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:[Android setOnCheckedChangeListener calls again when old view comes back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372750/android-setoncheckedchangelistener-calls-again-when-old-view-comes-back).
Just use the `buttonView.isShown()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(buttonView.isShown()) {
        dbManager.allDao().setTodoIsDone(todo.getTodoId(), isChecked); //sets the isDone attribute of the database
        todo.setDone(isChecked);
    }
}
```